# Triying to manage window with hotkeys using SetWindowsHookEx and SetForegroundWindow

Tags: c#, setwindowshookex, setforegroundwindow

im triying to create a tool, to manage some windows, like when i press a key i would change focus to the next window and so on
this is the method i wrote to set focus to the next window in my list

```
public void RoundRobinFunc()
{
    if (indexofCurrentRound == Windows.Count)
    {
        indexofCurrentRound = 0;
        SetForegroundWindow(Windows[indexofCurrentRound].HandlerIDD);
        indexofCurrentRound++;
    }
    else if (indexofCurrentRound < Windows.Count)
        {
        SetForegroundWindow(Windows[indexofCurrentRound].HandlerIDD);
        indexofCurrentRound++;
    }
}
```

and this is the method i use in my keylog class to execute the above method using hotkeys

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    Form1 form1T = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            var keyName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), vkCode);
            if (form1T.CheckKeys(keyName))
            {
            form1T.RoundRobinFunc();
            }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

the problem is when im debugging everything works perfect, when i press my desire key it would set the next window to be in the foreground, now the problem comes when im using release build, it would get messy, like when i press my desire key, it will switch to the next window once and get stuck there, wont switch to a new window never, its a complete diferent behivour from my debug test, so i dont know how to debug something that works when debugging but wont work outside visual studio.

Comment: You can switch to Release build and still debug in VS. Some things may be a bit odd, such as variables missing values or lines of code being skipped or not breakpointed. Let's see the DLL import definitions, and the code to setup the hook. I note you are not processing the vkCode [according to the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85))

Comment: i mean, when the program is outside visual studio as a standalone program, it will act wrong, while im running it off visual studio everything works just perfect =/

Comment: Lower two bytes are repeat count, next byte is the scan code which is what you are probably looking for. Then you have ALT flag, transition flag and previous value flag

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what u said, can u explain a little more please? also, if i use "SendKeys" in each window, everything start to work perfect in the release version =/, so it has bugs, and after using sendkeys in each window it will work

Comment: I mean that `vkCode` has various bits that are set depending on what is pressed and how long for, it's not just a simple keycode. Lookup the documentation that I linked

Comment: and if i use sendkeys, close the windows and reopen them again, my program keeps working, so sendkeys most be activating something in my program that makes it work

Comment: i dont think is a problem with vkcode, as its registeering the key been pressed but the round robin method is getting messy